# Use data to get standard devation of "Value" from table column

Tags: mysql

I have a database that stores answers from exam. I want to use 3 column which are question_id, student_id and value (0 and 1).

I'm trying to use two columns to get its standard deviation which is student_id (distinct) and value (0 and 1)

sampledata:
[image: sampledata]

testdata:
[image: testdata]

Comment: Please edit your question and include a sample table with data.  Make sure to indicate that the table is what you want to use with the query, and ideally show us the output you expect.

Comment: I just need the standard deviation result from datas in the table. Sample data's are in the link.

Comment: [sample data from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CDiS.png)

Comment: _Which_ of the two tables do you want to use?  By the way, the reason we are trying to clarify your question is so that it will be helpful to others.  As of right  now, it probably would not be.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CDiS.png
I want to use that data to get standard deviation of total correct answers which is in value="1"

Comment: MySQL STDDEV(expression) function returns the population standard deviation of expression. Read the docs.

Comment: I have tried that using this

SELECT STDDEV(st.total) from(SELECT count(value) as total FROM `main_answer` where ans=correct_ans and center_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' and exam_id='".$get_exam_status_id['exam_id']."') as st)

this returns, 0.